# time_ago_in_words causing error in rspec with Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a small rails app that is working just fine under Rails 4. I figured I would bump it up to 4.1, but I am now running into some rspec problems.

When rspec is run against a page with the following ERB.

```
 <%= t('environment.last_modified', 
  person: environment.recent_versions.first.username,
  time_modified: time_ago_in_words(environment.recent_versions.first.created_at) ) %>
```

and the en.yml for `last_modfied` is

```
last_modified: 'Modified by %{person} %{time_modified} ago.'
```

I get the following error when I run `rake`

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `content_tag' for I18n:Module
```

If I remove the `time_ago_in_words` it works fine. Also, it works fine under Rails 4.0

Note: This is only a problem for rspec. The page renders fine.

Comment: Did you try adding `include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper` in your spec file? If you're using `rspec-rails` this should be automatic for spec with `describe YourHelper, type: :view do`

Comment: I just put it at the top of my spec file (I assume this is where it would go?), and it didn't help. I am using rspec-rails, but it doesn't use describe (it uses `scenario`) and doesn't have `type: :view` anywhere

Comment: Looks like it might be [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15245), and it should be resolved - best guess is to make sure Rails is completely up to date, but besides that, not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15245) in Rails 4.1 and was address by going to Rails 4-1-stable[1]. Thanks d3vkit!

[1] gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: '4-1-stable'

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue with Rails 4.2.1 when I tried to test some draper decorators that were stored in `spec/decorators`. The tests would pass when running them via zeus, but would fail when running with `rspec` from the command line.

This seemed to be because the view helpers were not being included because the decorators were located outside the `spec/views` directory (despite labelling them as `type: :view`).

I was able to fix this by manually including the helpers in rails_helper.rb

```
config.include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper, type: :decorator
```

and by setting all decorator tests to `type: :decorator`.